# Dynamic countdown for online examination system

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am developing an online examination system in PHP and MySQL. Each exam has got its own period which is stored in the database, and the system shows one question at a time. When the submit button is pressed, it submits the question then displays the next one.

I tried to use the below code for the timer, and it appears for the student but once the first question is submitted and the second one appears the timer starts from the beginning again. For example, if the time was twenty minutes, it starts again from twenty minutes when the second question appears.

This is the code that I used:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("exam", $db);
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  test");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $min = $row['minutes'];
            }
        ?>
        <div id="quiz-time-left"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var min = '<?php echo $min;?>';
            var total_seconds = 60 * min;
            var c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
            var c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);

            function CheckTime() {
                document.getElementById("quiz-time-left").innerHTML = 'Time Left: ' + c_minutes + 'minutes' + c_seconds + 'seconds';
                if (total_seconds <= 0) {
                    setTimeout('document.quiz.submit()', 1);
                } else {
                    total_seconds = total_seconds - 1;
                    c_minutes = parseInt(total_seconds / 60);
                    c_seconds = parseInt(total_seconds % 60);
                    setTimeout("CheckTime()", 1000);
                }
            }
            setTimeout("CheckTime()", 1000);
        </script>
        <form name=quiz method="post" action="process.php"></form>
```

Comment: You need to store the time when the user first starts the exam in the database. Then you can always compare against that to find out how much time the user has left regardless of which question they are on.

Comment: Along with what @neuromatter said, my approach would be to simply use jquery to load the questions on the same page instead of doing a page refresh at all. This way it's one timer that you use, you don't have to store any data for it. This approach would only work if the questionaire would need to be restarted if page is refreshed or anything though. Could make a cleaner website for the user if you do it this way.

Comment: @neuromatter could you please show me how it is done, because i have googled about it so much and i couldn't find anything. It would be grate if you can help me with it